# Fatal error: $post is null?

Tags: posts, fatal-error

I am getting this fatal error when I try to add a new post, page or CPT.

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7502

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7503

> Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7507

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7762

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 3596

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 3822

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 5448

> Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 5448

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 4749

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "post_content" on null in /public_html/wp-admin/includes/post.php:795 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/wp-admin/post-new.php(66): get_default_post_to_edit() #1 {main} thrown in /public_html/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 795

When I re-activate my plugins, the error message changes to:

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7502

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7503

> Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7507

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 7762

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 3596

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 3822

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 5448

> Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 5448

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 4749

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_status" on null in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/seo-by-rank-math/includes/modules/sitemap/class-cache-watcher.php on line 96

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_author" on null in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/seo-by-rank-math/includes/modules/sitemap/class-cache-watcher.php on line 100

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_author" on null in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/seo-by-rank-math/includes/modules/sitemap/class-cache-watcher.php on line 102

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Elementor\TemplateLibrary\Source_Local::on_save_post(): Argument #2 ($post) must be of type WP_Post, null given, called in /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 326 and defined in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/template-library/sources/local.php:1114 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(326): Elementor\TemplateLibrary\Source_Local->on_save_post() #1 /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #2 /public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() #3 /public_html/wp-includes/post.php(4760): do_action() #4 /public_html/wp-admin/includes/post.php(753): wp_insert_post() #5 /public_html/wp-admin/post-new.php(66): get_default_post_to_edit() #6 {main} thrown in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/template-library/sources/local.php on line 1114

It seems the underlying problem is that `$post` is null.

To try and resolve, I have tried:

- Updating all plugins
- Disabling all plugins
- Changing the theme
- Re-installing WordPress (via wp-admin/update-core.php)
- Re-uploading root `/` files and `/wp-admin` and `/wp-includes` folders
- Checked database user permissions

This issue may coincide with me migrating the site to a new host server a couple of weeks ago, as this is the first post I have tried to add since then.

The site is running on PHP 8.1, but I have other sites running on the same server with the same PHP version that don't have this issue.

Can anyone advise why I am getting this issue and how to resolve?

Comment: Probably Elementor, try Regenerating CSS and media in Elementor settings

Comment: I've just tried **Regenerate Files & Data** which is in wp-admin > Elementor > Tools, but it hasn't fixed the problem. As I mentioned, this problem persists even if I disable *all* plugins.

Comment: Since you changed servers, did you check the "MU" (must use) plugins folder?  When you install in some environments (godaddy, wpengine, etc.), they install must use plugins which may cause issues.  Be sure to remove all of these folders when you are trying to get back to basics to trouble shoot

Comment: During website migration, AUTO_INCREMENT values within database tables are often getting lost. Within [prefix]_posts if you check the structure, do you see the ID column having AUTO_INCREMENT value?

Comment: @Adam, Thanks but I don't seem to have an MU plugins folder.

Comment: @Mowar I think you may have identified the issue. I've just checked my `wp_posts` table and not only does the `ID` column not have the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property, but the table has no indexes at all. In fact, none of my tables have any indexes. Do you know what would be the quickest way to add them? I have just tried this suggestion - https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-corrupted-wordpress-database-2/ - but it hasn't worked.

Comment: @Mowar Can you add an answer so I can award you the points, cheers.

Comment: Sure, I moved the comment into an answer. I'm glad that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the problem now. I got hold of my old database dump file from the old server.

The reason the indexes weren't added is because the sql contained rows like:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`xxxxxxxx`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `wp_
```

...which was not getting executed due to insufficient user permissions. This meant the consequent indexing lines were not executed either.

Solution was to comment out those lines, clear the new database then re-import. It's all good now and I can add posts again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem within the Elementor plugin, specifically in the `Source_Local::on_save_post()` method. The error states that the second argument passed to this method `$post` must be of type `WP_Post`, but it is receiving null instead.

If you're using any cache plugin, please ensure to purge all caches before and after updating the Elementor plugin and also try changes permalink

If the post name is already set in the permalink settings, update it to 'Plain' text, save the changes, then switch back to the 'Post name' option, save again, and make sure to clear the cache from both your caching plugin and your browser before testing

```
Settings → Permalinks → plain


Settings → Permalinks → Post
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay. I've now tried those, but to no avail. Please see my latest comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

During website migration, AUTO_INCREMENT values within database tables are often getting lost. Within [prefix]_posts if you check the structure, do you see the ID column having AUTO_INCREMENT value?